# multiple dynamic drop down submission on button click to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys i am working on a small project for my college. it consists of a table which is dynamic(linked to mysql table) and one cell in every record is a dynamic drop down(all are linked to mysql table). and the user has to choose from a list of drop down values for each drop down generated and it can also be left blank. here is the php code for that:

```
    <form class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
    <center><h2>NOMINATE ENTRY</h2></center>
    <p><center><font size='3'>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user",pass","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $dept = $_POST['department'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM prizemaster");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM studentmaster WHERE dept='$dept' and class='$class'");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Prize ID &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</th>
    <th>Prize Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    <th>Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prizeid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><select name='name'>";
    echo "<option></option>";
    while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    echo "<option value='".$drop['name']."'>" . $drop['name'] . "</option>"; 
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($result1, 0);
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?></center></font></div>
    <p>
    <center><button type="submit" formaction="stnomins.php">Nominate</button></center>
    </form>
```

the above is the form and when the nominate button is clicked i want this code to be executed for each and every drop down value selected:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$myname = $_POST['name'];
$sql2="SELECT * FROM studentmaster WHERE name='$myname'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2)or die(mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$mydept=$row['dept'];
$myclass=$row['class'];
$myregno=$row['regno'];
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql1="INSERT INTO studenttransaction (`transid`, `date`, `prizeid`, `regno`, `name`, `class`, `department`, `status`) VALUES ('' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , '', '$myregno', '$myname', '$myclass', '$mydept', '1')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

kindly help me out i need to submit it in 2 days. please explain with code because i am new to php and not fully known to it

Comment: Please explain your error/s

Comment: only the last drop down is inserted into mysql table. others are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated both of your html & php code, please have a look :

In form file:

```
echo "<td><select name='name[]'>"; // added [] here to make it array
echo "<option value=''>Select student</option>"; // added value & option item
```

These above lines of code have been modified accordingly in the file below

```
    <form class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
    <center><h2>NOMINATE ENTRY</h2></center>
    <p><center><font size='3'>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user",pass","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $dept = $_POST['department'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM prizemaster");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM studentmaster WHERE dept='$dept' and class='$class'");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Prize ID &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</th>
    <th>Prize Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    <th>Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prizeid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><select name='name[]'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select student</option>";
    while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    echo "<option value='".$drop['name']."'>" . $drop['name'] . "</option>"; 
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($result1, 0);
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?></center></font></div>
    <p>
    <center><button type="submit" name="nominate" formaction="stnomins.php">Nominate</button></center>
    </form>
```

Slightly updated your PHP code. Started a loop for each drop-down of names if button is clicked/submitted.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['nominate'])){
 foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $myname){
  //$myname = $_POST['name'];
  $sql2="SELECT * FROM studentmaster WHERE name='$myname'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2)or die(mysqli_error());
  if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $mydept=$row['dept'];
   $myclass=$row['class'];
   $myregno=$row['regno'];
   $sql1="INSERT INTO studenttransaction (`transid`, `date`, `prizeid`, `regno`, `name`, `class`, `department`, `status`) VALUES ('' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , '', '$myregno', '$myname', '$myclass', '$mydept', '1')";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
  }//if mysqli_fetch_array condition closed
 }// for loop closed     
}// if submit button(nominate) closed
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot sir it worked like a charm. also if a blank value is selected i want it to be entered as empty is it psbl???

Comment: yes. put an else condition against if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) And execute this sql.   $sql1="INSERT INTO studenttransaction (`transid`, `date`, `prizeid`, `regno`, `name`, `class`, `department`, `status`) VALUES ('' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , '', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', '1')";

Comment: Does blank value means no selection from the drop down? What actually you want to do(what actually you want to insert), please clarify.

Comment: if no name of student is selected ie. if select an option value is selected then all my fields should be blank or say "null" and the status field should be 0.

Answer (score -1):

its working fine. I have another doubt is that how to echo the value of drop down when a drop down value is selected.Anybody who knows the answer of it, kindly provide the solution of it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should not be placed here. Consider asking another question